# Como abrir uma tela com formulário pré preenchido com HTML?

Tags: html, python, django

Gostaria de saber, como abrir um formulário cujos campos já estejam previamente preenchidos com os dados do usuário(resultantes de uma pesquisa no banco de dados), ficando a cargo dele somente editar as informações.

Estou utilizando `Django` para programar, consegui fazer o formulário, porém não consigo recuperar ele pra edição.

Eu até consigo utilizando a função `{{ form.as_p }}`, porém eu gostaria de recuperar esses dados utilizando `<input>`, tem como?

Atualmente minha view para editar está da seguinte forma:

```
def editar(request, pk): # Funcao para editar um aluno
post = get_object_or_404(Aluno, pk=pk)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = PostForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    if form.is_valid():
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.save()
        return redirect('aluno:detalhes', pk=post.pk)
else:
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
return render(request, 'aluno/editar.html', {'form': form})
```

E no html está assim:

```
  <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
                        <!--Entrada do nome do aluno-->
                        <label class="campos" for="nome">Nome:</label><br>
                        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required autofocus >
                        <p></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para preencher manualmente o valor das tags de `input` no seu `form` você precisa referenciar os campos do formulário Django, pegar o `.value` deles e preencher no `value` do `input`, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" value="{{ form.nome.value|default:"" }}" required autofocus>
{# Tome nota para a tag "default" que é útil quando o campo está vazio pois em alguns casos ele ficaria mostrando o campo nulo "None" do Python #}
```

Answer (score 0):

Na sua view, na hora de instanciar o form, acrescente a instancia do objeto desejado.

```
meu_objeto = MyObject.objects.get(pk=meu_id)
form = MyForm(instance=meu_objeto)
```

Isso deveria resolver seu problema.

Comment: Então, tou fazendo algo parecido, segue um trecho da minha View:
def editar(request, pk): 
    post = get_object_or_404(Aluno, pk=pk)
    form = PostForm(instance=post)
    return render(request, 'aluno/editar.html', {'form': form})

Comment: Editei minha pergunta com um trecho do código atual